# Can't get LinkedList implementation to work (Python)

Tags: python, linked-list

I felt i should make another question from earlier today, because the problem is much different from before. And i wanted to leave the other question as reference. Also it was already pretty cluttered. If this is a problem, let me know.

From what i can tell, nothing is added to the linked list. This doesn't print anything or give me any errors, and that is my problem. It's supposed to insert words alphabetically. Everything seems logical to me. I redid most of my insert().

I feed it files with single words on each line.
The only functions of the list are insert and print.
Example text (not including the blank lines):

Here is the code:

```
import sys, os, copy, fileinput
class Node:
    def __init__(self, word):
        self.data = word
        self.next = None
    def nextNode(self):
        if self.next is not None:
            return self.next
        else:
            return None
    def getData(self):
        return self.data
    def setNext(self, node):
        self.next = node
    def hasNext(self):
        if self.next == None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

class Linked_List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node(None)
        self.isempty = True
    def insert(self, word):
        newNode = Node(word)
        #Look for position to insert:

        #When empty
        if self.isempty == True:
            self.isempty = False
            self.head = newNode
        #When has more than two nodes

        else:
            prev = None
            current = self.head
            nextFound = False #the next would be the current when it is less than node

            while nextFound == False and current != None:
                if current.getData() < newNode.getData():
                    prev = copy.copy(current)
                    current = current.nextNode()
                else:
                    nextFound = True

            if prev == None:
                nextNode = copy.copy(current)
                self.head = newNode
                self.head.setNext(nextNode)
            else:
                prev.setNext(newNode)
                newNode.setNext(current)

    def printLinkedList(self):
        if self.head.getData() == None:
            print("The file was empty.")
        else:
            prints = self.head
            while prints.hasNext():
                sys.stdout.write(prints.getData() + '\n')
                prints.setNext(prints.nextNode())

linkedlist = Linked_List()

wordlist = ["hello", "jupiter", "albacore", "shrimp", "axe"]
for line in wordlist:
    linkedlist.insert(line)
linkedlist.printLinkedList()
```

Comment: To debug things like this, you either need to run it in a debugger or visualizer, or add a bunch of logging (e.g., `print` statements) to see what's happening at different places. Once you do that, it usually becomes obvious where things are going wrong, and then you only have a line or two to look at, instead of the whole program.

Comment: As a side note: never use `x == None` for comparison; use `x is None` if you need to, but in many cases just `not x` is all you need. And likewise `x == True` is rarely necessary; you can usually just use `x`.

Comment: Another side note: You rarely want to add methods like `getData` in Python; you can just access it as `node.data`.

Comment: What is the logic behind the line ``if current.getData() < newNode.getData():``?

Comment: hmmm, i assumed there wasn't a debugger for a scripting language like python. And someone advised me to use ==, i guess i will not.

Comment: Mike, the logic is alphabetical ordering, so string comparison. To know where i can insert the word.

Comment: @user1831680: There's [a debugger in the stdlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), and various GUI wrappers around it. There are also interactive visualizers, and even [an online one](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html).

Comment: One more note: in your `nextNode` function, you're returning `self.next` if it's not `None`, and `None` if it _is_ `None`. In other words, it does the exact same thing as `return self.next`. So, just do that. (Or, again, even better to scrap your getters and setters entirely and just use `self.next` instead of `self.nextNode()` everywhere.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're making a copy of the previous node here:

```
prev = copy.copy(current)
```

So, when you update that copy in-place here:

```
prev.setNext(newNode)
```

… it doesn't affect the original node that's actually linked into the list. (Nor do you replace the original node with the modified copy.) So, nothing ever gets changed.

To fix it, just remove the `copy.copy`.

---

When you fix that, there's another bug in your code that will lead to an infinite loop of printing out "absolute", in `printLinkedList`:

```
prints.setNext(prints.nextNode())
```

This doesn't do anything useful—it sets `prints.next` to `prints.next`. Crucially, it doesn't update the variable `prints` to point to the next node. Just do this:

```
prints = prints.nextNode()
```

---

And with both of those changes, the output from your original example is:

```
absolute
crisp
daytona
demand
extra
```

---

However, notice that your new example is missing one value:

```
albacore
axe
hello
jupiter
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out where the `shrimp` went. (You can always post a new question if you get stuck.)

---

If you're wondering how I found the problem:

I added a `print` statement after the `while` loop that dumps out a bunch of information about the found previous node, including its `id`, and another `print` before and after the `setNext`, so I could see that I was successfully setting the `next` member of the first node each time through the loop, but it was always a *different* first node each time through.

Then I added a `print` to show me the `id` of each nodes, and it was clear that the found previous node each time wasn't any of the nodes actually in the list. At which point the `copy.copy` finally jumped out at me.

Comment: I see that when using a quite sorted 50k file, this is very slow. I've been waiting for a bit, and it's still going. do you know what could be the problem? I know insertion sort should be fast, so this should be fast.

Comment: @user1831680: Actually, insertion sort is only fast for very small lists. For large lists, it's quadratic, meaning sorting 50000 elements takes 50000*50000 steps, while a log-linear sort like quicksort or mergesort only takes 50000*16 steps.

Comment: @user1831680: And using a linked list adds _another_ slowdown, because to search through a list of 50000 entries takes 50000 steps, and you have to do that for each of the 50000 inserts. There are tricks to take care of that problem when the input is a linked list and you can destroy the original while building the new one, but if you don't implement those tricks, you don't benefit from them of course.

Comment: @user1831680: The Wikipedia article on [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) has a lot more detail on all of this.

Comment: @user1831680: No, it wouldn't be faster. Think about it: In order to find the place to insert the 10000th element, because it's probably also 10000th in sorted order, you will have to search through all 9999 elements to find its proper place.